# How to create a WPF application where the user can drag a Canvas (grouping canvas) around?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

I have recently tried to make an application that enables users to drag the controls around
which is very crucial for my project, because it will help them to freely move the object around and prevent it from interfering with other tasks
i have tried creating a new window and using ***Me.Dragmove()*** but the controls are too much to do as such! 


[image]
Can any one **please** help me tackle this problem? Thanks in Advance!!! 

Coding language **VB.NET**
Programming software: Expression Blend 4 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2012

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, using a third party library can be useful in this scenario. I remember ComponentOne has a C1DraDropManager class that can reduce a lot of work and enable drag/drop features in few simple steps.

Comment: But there must be a way of doing this.